# Play 2.3 with Scala, converting JSON Array to Sequence

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Welcome,

I really wanted to avoid this but i give up for now. I am trying to traverse through json array and withdraw some elements and put them to sequence. I tried many options, tried all from play docs, many attempts and still i have the same error: null pointer exception when my method try to withdraw elements. So my json example is:

```
[
  {
    "var1": "xx",
    "var2": "xxx",
    "var3": 111
  },
  {
    "var1": "yy",
    "var2": "yyy",
    "var3": 222 
  },
  {
    "var1": "zz",
    "var2": "zzz",
    "var3": 333    
  }
]
```

I defined many configurations of Reads, last one is like that but doesnt want to compile even ;/

```
case class Vars1(vars: Seq[String])
val var1Reads: Reads[String] = (__ \ "var1").read[String]
implicit val vars1Reads: Reads[Vars1] = ((__).read[Seq[String]])(Vars1.apply _)
```

I want to create Sequence or List, this not important, from only var1 from each element of this array. It can be pure sequence, or case class with sequence or other. Just how to iterate through json arrays? I tried many configurations, reading var1 is nonproblematic, but when i want read all vars 1 from each element of array then i have null pointer exception. Please, anyone can point me in a good direction, give me a hint what i am doing wrong? Please don't blame I am newbie at programming, and i started to learn scala and play framework.

Thank you for any help.

Update:

I have tried this one too:

```
implicit val vars1Reads = (__).read(Reads.list((__).read[String])).map( var => Vars(var))
```

but still i have the same error:

```
[NoSuchElementException: JsError.get]
```

Comment: Declare your reads to be lazy, e.g., `implicit lazy val vars1Reads`.  That's an annoying and altogether confusing source of NPEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of parsing this is to let Play parse the array body as a `Seq[_]`, that is, a sequence of objects.

I would suggest that each item in your array should be represented by a case class, e.g.

```
case class Var1(var1: String)
```

This provides a useful type upon which to add validation of the input data from the JSON.

You can add an implicit `Reads` in an appropriate location, e.g.

```
object Var1 {
  implicit val var1Reads: Reads[Var1] = {
    ((__ \ "var1").read[String]).map(Var1.apply _)
  }
}
```

Note that the read/write macros have a limitation where they do not work in the documented way where the case class has a single field - see http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/131bx7pcyd/play2-1-scala-json-writing-a-reads-writes-for-a-single-field-case-class
- This is why the `map` call is added. The macro should work as documented when there are 2 or more fields.

You may then use this to create a Seq[Var1], e.g.

```
def test = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
  val result = request.body.validate[Seq[Var1]]
  ...
}
```

And the result (here I am just printing out the value of result.toString) is:

```
$ curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json" --data '[{"var1": "3", "var2": "4"}, {"var1": "7"}]' http://localhost:9000/test
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 34

JsSuccess(List(Var1(3), Var1(7)),)
```

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments below, you can simplify the `Reads[Var1]` implementation using a macro like this:

```
implicit val var1Reads = Json.reads[Var1]
```

This will only do what you want, if the field is called `var1`, i.e.

```
case class Var1(var1: String)
```

Comment: The limitation on single-field case classes was fixed in version 2.1-RC2, according to the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception).

Comment: It does say that. However, `((__ \ "var1").read[String])(Var1.apply _)` results in the compilation error `Overloaded method value [read] cannot be applied to  (String => controllers.Var1)`, while the same pattern applied to multiple fields does work (with Play 2.3.4). My current assumption is that not all situations were fixed, but more investigation is needed.

Comment: Ah, I think the thing that was fixed was macro generation, e.g. `implicit val var1Reads = Json.reads[Var1]`. I can confirm that it works. I've found that macro generation is reliable enough that I haven't needed to write my own.

Comment: That's true, so in this case, `implicit val var1Reads = Json.reads[Var1]` does work fine. And I think this matches what the question requires, as long as the field is named `var1`.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you very much for help. It works like a charm now and need a little less code as i thought, especially with macros. Thanks again. I need to learn a lot.